# Error when trying to make confusion matrix

Tags: r, random-forest

```
cm = table(obs = test[,14], pred)
```

`Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I am trying to output the confusion matrix of my random forest model on the testing data, but I'm getting this error. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error function tells us that one of the items in `test[,14]` or `pred` is missing (`NA`), and the `table()` function you are using cannot handle missing values. I expect you can get a confusion matrix by first eliminating elements of both vectors where either vector is `NA`.

Note that the `table()` function you are using does not seem to be the base `R` `table()` function. I expect it is part of a package you have loaded.